# How to display ascending or descending for the contents shown in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

output shown now:

```
1234/45/67-9
1234/45/67-8
1234/45/67-7
1234/45/67-6
1234/45/67-5
1234/45/67-4
1234/45/67-3
1234/45/67-22
1234/45/67-2
1234/45/67-10
1234/45/67-1
1234/45/67
```

output needed:

```
1234/45/67-22
1234/45/67-10
1234/45/67-9
1234/45/67-8
1234/45/67-7
1234/45/67-6
1234/45/67-5
1234/45/67-4
1234/45/67-3
1234/45/67-2
1234/45/67-1
1234/45/67



SELECT invoiceNo
FROM invoice
WHERE invoiceNo LIKE '1234/45/67%'
ORDER BY invoiceNo DESC
```

i want the output to be shown in descending but it is not able to show in a proper manner? how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefix is always 10 characters long then you can chop it up with [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and covert the second chunk to a number with [`cast`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

```
select invoiceno
from invoice
where invoiceno like '1234/45/67%'
order by substring(invoiceno from 1 for 10),
         cast(substring(invoiceno from 11) as decimal);
```

Casting the second part to a number gets them to sort like numbers rather than strings so that `-10` goes before `-1` rather than the other way around. If you're always going to be using a prefix of the form `9999/99/99` in your WHERE clause then you can simplify the ORDER BY:

```
select invoiceno
from invoice
where invoiceno like '1234/45/67%'
order by cast(substring(invoiceno from 11) as decimal);
```

Comment: got a doubt if the table contains thousands of rows will it take more time to load for this query???

Comment: @dude: The `substring` call isn't free. If it becomes too expensive then you'd probably want to break the `invoiceno` into two separate columns so that you could sort them without the string wrangling.

Comment: how to achieve it? if i face such a problem

Comment: @dude: add two new columns for the two parts of the invoice number, split the in oice number into two parts on INSERT, and then `order by part1, part2` as needed. Basically, you'd precompute the `substring` calls pay for the computation in little pieces instead of every time you sort.

Answer (score 1):

Use an helper calculated field cast to `integer`, like this:

```
SELECT invoiceNo, CAST(SUBSTR(invoiceNo FROM 11) AS INT) AS invoiceNumber
FROM invoice
WHERE invoiceNo LIKE '1234/45/67%'
ORDER BY invoiceNumber DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT invoiceNo,
    @third_part:=SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoiceno, '/', -1) tp
  FROM
    invoice
  WHERE
    invoiceNo LIKE '1234/45/67%'
  ) t
ORDER BY
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(tp, '-', 1) * 1 DESC,
  IF (LOCATE('-', tp) = 0, 0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(tp, '-', -1) * 1) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT invoiceNo
FROM invoice
ORDER BY cast(substring(invoiceNo from 11) as decimal) ASC
```